# How to project a picture onto a bubble surface programmatically

Tags: android, graphics, opengl-es

I want to implement an effect that, showing a picture on a bubble surface with the picture looks like surrounding the bubble surface. But I don't know how to do this kind of things...

[image: like]

I am doing it in Android platform, should I use OpenGL ES for this ? Or just some 2D transformation can achieve this effect ?

One more question is, I want to create many interesting graphics effects like the PhotoShop's various filter, is there any books/articles I can refer for this kind of things ? Is this kind of work belongs to the "Digital Image Processing" field or some other computer graphics related fields ?

Comment: You can check something like this http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Map_projection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Or just some 2D transformation

This effect is a nonlinear transformation, so doing through the 2D (linear) transformations being available will not work. You can do it using OpenGL by numerous ways. I'm currently thinking about some easy to understand way to convey, what you need to do. Basically you need to implement some kind of refraction or nonlinear radial warp.

Say `p` is the center of your bubble (in 2D), and `r` the position relative to `p`, then the undistorted picture is given by `r+p`. Now you want to distort it toward the edges. A parabolic distortion comes to mid, i.e. instead of `r+p` you'd show the pixel `r + (|p|^2)*p/|p|`

Comment: Thanks. But I don't quite get your idea. You mean, use a 2D nonlinear transformation ? And |p|^2 means  square(|p|) ?

Comment: @YangBo: Yes, to a 2D nonlinear transform. |p| means "length of p" and ^2 means square, yes.

Comment: Finally, I found using a 3D sphere in OpenGL with the picture as a texture can have this kind of warp...  I am trying to use fragment shader to achieve this now.